# UI-Router: state params in child state when parent abstract

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following ui-router definition:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'partials/wrapper.html',
            controller: 'WrapperCtrl'
        })
        .state('main.notidetails', {
            controller: 'NotificationsDetailsCtrl',
            url: '/notidetails/:id',
            params: ['id'],
            templateUrl: 'partials/notificationDetails.html'
        });
```

But when launching the app I get:

> Error: Both params and url are specified in state 'main.notidetails'

What should I do different? I want 'notidetails' to remain as a child state and have it's parameter

Comment: If you only need to retrieve the id from the url in your controller you dont need to user the params-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error says it all. You either have to use parameters in URL or in `params`. Delete `params` from your state. Inject `$stateParams` it to your state controller and you can access your parameters like so `$stateParams.id`.

So your code will go like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'partials/wrapper.html',
        controller: 'WrapperCtrl'
    })
    .state('main.notidetails', {
        controller: 'NotificationsDetailsCtrl',
        url: '/notidetails/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partials/notificationDetails.html'
    });
```